# rails generate migration create_articles not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my console I put `rails generate migration create_articles`, but I got this message below my console.

I had just started to work on my rails app.

```
from /home/nitrous/code/rails_projects/alpha/.bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /home/nitrous/code/rails_projects/alpha/.bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /home/nitrous/code/rails_projects/alpha/.bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bug of `spring`. And it was fixed in latest `spring` version.

You can update latest your `spring` version via command:

```
bundle update spring && bundle exec spring binstub --remove --all && bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gem query --local
```

Then fine the version fo spring. Uninstall the gem with:

```
gem unistall spring
```

Then,in your gemfile put the specific version of spring:

```
gem 'spring', '~> 1.7.1'
```

I think this is a better way.